# Multi part column name could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm trying to write a query but getting an error : Multi part identifier "dlv.delivery_num" could not be bound.

I'm not able to figure out whats actually wrong with the query. Can someone please look into it.

Here's query:

```
SELECT shpUID.attribute_value                               shipunitid, 
       pal.container_id                                     palletid, 
       cas.container_id                                     caseid, 
       dl.delivery_line_id, 
       po.attribute_value                                   po, 
       Max(Isnull(comm.attribute_value, ''))                commodity, 
       Sum(Isnull(Cast(wgt.attribute_value AS FLOAT), 0.0)) weight, 
       Sum(Isnull(Cast(vol.attribute_value AS FLOAT), 0.0)) volume 
FROM   container pal 
       INNER JOIN container cas 
               ON pal.container_id = cas.parent_container_id 
                  AND pal.container_type = 'Pallet' 
                  AND cas.container_type = 'Case' 
       INNER JOIN container_detail cdtl 
               ON cdtl.container_id = cas.container_id 
       INNER JOIN container_delivery cd 
               ON cd.detail_id = cdtl.detail_id 
       INNER JOIN delivery_line dl 
               ON cd.delivery_line_id = dl.delivery_line_id 
       INNER JOIN delivery dlv 
               ON dlv.delivery_num = dl.delivery_num 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute shpUID 
                    ON shpUID.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id 
                       AND shpUID.attribute_type = 'SHIP_UNIT_ID' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute wgt 
                    ON wgt.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id 
                       AND wgt.attribute_type = 'Weight' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute vol 
                    ON vol.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id 
                       AND vol.attribute_type = 'Volume' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute comm 
                    ON comm.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id 
                       AND comm.attribute_type = 'COMMODITY' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute po 
                    ON po.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id 
                       AND po.attribute_type = 'PO' 
WHERE  pal.container_id = '00007712120038613557' 
       AND dlv.delivery_num IN ( 'D631239-S354', 'D631372-S558' ) 
       AND dlv.delivery_type_id = 'OUTBOUND' 
GROUP  BY pal.container_id, 
          cas.container_id, 
          dl.delivery_line_id, 
          shpUID.attribute_value, 
          po.attribute_value 
UNION 
SELECT shpUID.attribute_value                               shipunitid, 
       pal.container_id                                     palletid, 
       'UNKNOWN'                                            caseid, 
       dl.delivery_line_id, 
       po.attribute_value                                   po, 
       Max(Isnull(comm.attribute_value, ''))                commodity, 
       Sum(Isnull(Cast(wgt.attribute_value AS FLOAT), 0.0)) weight, 
       Sum(Isnull(Cast(vol.attribute_value AS FLOAT), 0.0)) volume 
FROM   container pal 
       INNER JOIN container_detail cdtl 
               ON cdtl.container_id = pal.container_id 
                  AND pal.container_type = 'Pallet' 
       INNER JOIN container_delivery cd 
               ON cd.detail_id = cdtl.detail_id 
       INNER JOIN delivery_line dl 
               ON cd.delivery_line_id = dl.delivery_line_id 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute shpUID 
                    ON shpUID.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id 
                       AND shpUID.attribute_type = 'SHIP_UNIT_ID' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute wgt 
                    ON wgt.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id 
                       AND wgt.attribute_type = 'Weight' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute vol 
                    ON vol.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id 
                       AND vol.attribute_type = 'Volume' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute comm 
                    ON comm.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id 
                       AND comm.attribute_type = 'COMMODITY' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute po 
                    ON po.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id 
                       AND po.attribute_type = 'PO' 
WHERE  pal.container_id = '00007712120038613557' 
       AND dlv.delivery_num IN ( 'D631239-S354', 'D631372-S558' ) 
       AND dlv.delivery_type_id = 'OUTBOUND' 
GROUP  BY pal.container_id, 
          dl.delivery_line_id, 
          shpUID.attribute_value, 
          po.attribute_value
```

Comment: the table `delivery` has a column named `delivery_num`?

Comment: Yes, its having that column.

Comment: You miss a "inner join delivery dlv on ..." in the second part of you query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

second part of your `UNION` doesnt have alias `dlv`

The `SELECT` statement after `UNION` has below `WHERE` condition.

`AND dlv.delivery_num IN ( 'D631239-S354', 'D631372-S558' )`

But, your `FROM` part doesn't have any table aliased as `dlv`.

Answer (score 0):

your issue that you have not an alias `dlv` in the second query, see the following code:

```
SELECT shpUID.attribute_value                               shipunitid, 
       pal.container_id                                     palletid, 
       cas.container_id                                     caseid, 
       dl.delivery_line_id, 
       po.attribute_value                                   po, 
       Max(Isnull(comm.attribute_value, ''))                commodity, 
       Sum(Isnull(Cast(wgt.attribute_value AS FLOAT), 0.0)) weight, 
       Sum(Isnull(Cast(vol.attribute_value AS FLOAT), 0.0)) volume 
FROM   container pal 
       INNER JOIN container cas ON pal.container_id = cas.parent_container_id AND pal.container_type = 'Pallet' AND cas.container_type = 'Case' 
       INNER JOIN container_detail cdtl  ON cdtl.container_id = cas.container_id 
       INNER JOIN container_delivery cd ON cd.detail_id = cdtl.detail_id 
       INNER JOIN delivery_line dl  ON cd.delivery_line_id = dl.delivery_line_id 
       INNER JOIN delivery dlv  ON dlv.delivery_num = dl.delivery_num 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute shpUID ON shpUID.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id AND shpUID.attribute_type = 'SHIP_UNIT_ID' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute wgt ON wgt.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id AND wgt.attribute_type = 'Weight' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute vol ON vol.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id AND vol.attribute_type = 'Volume' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute comm ON comm.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id AND comm.attribute_type = 'COMMODITY' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute po ON po.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id AND po.attribute_type = 'PO' 
WHERE  pal.container_id = '00007712120038613557' 
       AND dlv.delivery_num IN ( 'D631239-S354', 'D631372-S558' ) 
       AND dlv.delivery_type_id = 'OUTBOUND' 
GROUP  BY pal.container_id, 
          cas.container_id, 
          dl.delivery_line_id, 
          shpUID.attribute_value, 
          po.attribute_value 
UNION 





SELECT shpUID.attribute_value                               shipunitid, 
       pal.container_id                                     palletid, 
       'UNKNOWN'                                            caseid, 
       dl.delivery_line_id, 
       po.attribute_value                                   po, 
       Max(Isnull(comm.attribute_value, ''))                commodity, 
       Sum(Isnull(Cast(wgt.attribute_value AS FLOAT), 0.0)) weight, 
       Sum(Isnull(Cast(vol.attribute_value AS FLOAT), 0.0)) volume 
FROM   container pal 
       INNER JOIN container_detail cdtl 
               ON cdtl.container_id = pal.container_id 
                  AND pal.container_type = 'Pallet' 
       INNER JOIN container_delivery cd 
               ON cd.detail_id = cdtl.detail_id 
       INNER JOIN delivery_line dl 
               ON cd.delivery_line_id = dl.delivery_line_id 
       INNER JOIN delivery dlv  ON dlv.delivery_num = dl.delivery_num 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute shpUID 
                    ON shpUID.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id 
                       AND shpUID.attribute_type = 'SHIP_UNIT_ID' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute wgt 
                    ON wgt.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id 
                       AND wgt.attribute_type = 'Weight' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute vol 
                    ON vol.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id 
                       AND vol.attribute_type = 'Volume' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute comm 
                    ON comm.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id 
                       AND comm.attribute_type = 'COMMODITY' 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN attribute po 
                    ON po.attribute_id = cdtl.attribute_id 
                       AND po.attribute_type = 'PO' 
WHERE  pal.container_id = '00007712120038613557' 
       AND dlv.delivery_num IN ( 'D631239-S354', 'D631372-S558' ) 
       AND dlv.delivery_type_id = 'OUTBOUND' 
GROUP  BY pal.container_id, 
          dl.delivery_line_id, 
          shpUID.attribute_value, 
          po.attribute_value
```